# Remove /author/ from the author profile url

Tags: author, profiles

I'm trying to figure out the best way to remove /author/ from the profile URL of my users. I tried using the method in the link below and although it worked, it also prevented me from accessing any of my other pages that used a page template. So not sure if there's a tweak I need to make to the code?

I would like to do this through the functions file and not use a plugin so any guidance is much appreciated.

```
add_action('init', 'cng_author_base');
function cng_author_base() {
   global $wp_rewrite;
   $author_slug = ''; // change slug name
   $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you can't do that because you've overlapped the "page" and "author" sections in the namespace.

See, with your setup, then given a URL like http://example.com/whatever, WordPress has no way to distinguish whether "whatever" is an author or a Page.

To do this, you'd need to add a lot more code to add extra querying during the rewrite parsing, basically. Which means that you should use a plugin to do it, if you still want to do it at all.

Comment: Dang, ok, do you know of a solid plugin that can do this in a multisite instance?

Comment: No, I don't know of any existing plugin to do this. That's not to say one isn't out there, I just don't know of one. It's not something that comes up a lot.